# Datetime array to array with dates, get corresponding time afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datetime

Specific situation.. I'm having an array filled with datetimes I pull in via an api.

Users should be able to select a date from a datepicker (only showing dates available in the array) and afterwards see the corresponding time.

So what I've done..

The original array is obtained via php, so before starting to populate the datepicker with possible dates I create an extra array with dates only.
Since I maintain the key's it's possible to put these 2 arrays next to eachother.

Array looks as following:
["8-8-2017,07:00", "26-8-2017,07:00"];

So far so good...
After a user picks a date I trigger this to be able to start digging for the time corresponding that date.

Now it's getting messy...

```
    $('#datepick').datepicker().on("input change", function(e) {

    $("#uur").text('');

    var selecteddate = e.target.value;
    var searchArr = datesArray;

    var ind = searchArr.indexOf(selecteddate.toString());

    var result = datesArray.filter(function(item) {
        return typeof item == 'string' && item.indexOf(selecteddate.toString()) > -1;
    });

    var afterComma = result.toString().substr(result.toString().indexOf(",") + 1);

    var final = afterComma.replace(":", "u");

    $("#uur").text("De warming up party gaat van start rond " + final);

});
```

The result is that this only works on the last element of the array.
Because I'm splitting based on the comma's. Now I know the easiest way to work arround this would be to change the , that's seperating date and time in another symbol but still I'm wondering why this couldn't be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You convert whole array to string every time. You should change following code:

```
var afterComma = result.toString().substr(result.toString().indexOf(",") + 1);
```

To this;

```
var afterComma = item.toString().substr(item.toString().indexOf(",") + 1);
```

Edit:
I also missed the loop above

```
//for every item in result, afterComma will refer to related minute string
for (var item in result) {
    var afterComma = item.toString().substr(item.toString().indexOf(",") + 1);
    // Do rest here
}
```

Comment: Hi Progressive, thanks for your input.
I've changed the line of code as per your suggestion. However it's not working yet. I'm getting an error stating item is not defined.

Comment: Hello Maarten, I edited my answer. If you clerify your final variable and the message, I can provide more accurate answer for the problem